# Create a double join query using Rails Admin

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, rails-admin, rails-models

I am trying to create a form using Rails Admin, version 4.0.0. For this form I have tables called items, locations, cities and item_in_city. Tables are related in the following ways:

1. items table has a column called location which is array or location ids where item is present
2. location table has a column called city_id which connects it to city table
3. there is item_in_city table which has item_id and its corresponding list of city_id

Now, I want to create a form using Rails Admin, where I can give option to add a new item. While adding this new item I want to give an option to select (multiple) cities and corresponding to cities I want to give list of locations which can be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution, So I thought of posting it as it can be useful to others. Combination of city name and location can be posted by defining an enum method in the following way

```
def location_enum
   Location.all.collect {|l| [ l.city.name + ' ' + l.name, l.id] }.sort
end
```